# Software or a tool in a software that calculates 75% darker/lighter color of a given color?

Tags: color, gimp, inkscape, color-conversion, open-source

I am using Inkscape for vector and Gimp for raster graphics. They are quite powerful though open-source.

Can somebody recommend me if there is open-source software like Inkscape or Gimp or maybe a tool inside mentioned ones that can calculate 75% darker color of a given color?
Well 75% is not a requirement, it can be for example 50% or 42%, whatever.
Also could I do the same thing for 75% lighter color or 64% lighter color.

I am building a software and so far I relied on my coded function to calculate given value. But I need to test this function. I need a proof from outside world that this function is calculating the correct value.

Comment: Do you want to check values manually, or do you need to make these calculations programmatically? I've used less.js's [color operation functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations) to do this type of thing before.

Comment: Well manually. I have the code already. Just need to prove it works ok.

Comment: Can you give some examples, what is meant by x% darker? For example for #255:127:000.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/75417/how-to-make-a-given-color-a-bit-darker-or-lighter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this yourself with a calculator and the HSB value of any colour.

HSB = Hue, Saturation and Brightness.

Take the existing brightness value, and add or subtract whatever percentage amount you need, and enter that. Bingo!

Comment: Sounds promising! Will try it :)

Comment: Any ideas where can I find HSB in Gimp or Inkscape?

Comment: Search google for Gimp (or Inkscape) and HSB or HSL, they're the same thing, and I can't imaging they're not part of these apps.

Comment: If they're not in these apps, there's bound to be online convertors for any colour format to and fro from HSB/HSL

Answer (score 1):

W3schools has a colors picker tool and it has a few different options to modify a colour including the one you are asking for. 
Here is the link:
http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp