# Creating Equal Colour Steps when Transitioning between Colours

Tags: color, color-theory

If i have 2 HSL colours and i'll like to find the colour values in equal steps between the 2 colours, how would I go about this?  Is there an equation or an online resource that would do this?

**Example**

If I have two colours:

`hsl(195, 53%, 79%)` and `hsl(203, 36%, 14%)`

I want to create 6 transition stages of equal linear measurement between the 2 colours. What I'll end up with is 8 colours in total — the 2 original colours and the 6 from the transitioning stages of the 1st colour to the 2nd.

Many thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a series of colors between two colors](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83866/generating-a-series-of-colors-between-two-colors)

Answer (score 1):

8 colours in total is 7 steps (not including the first colour obviously)

Find the difference between the start and end values for H, S, and L

Divide the difference by the number of steps

Subtract the value of each step from the previous step, repeat

Round the numbers to integers

[image]

[image]