# Convert color to another color with exactly the same values?

Tags: color, rgb

I have a website with several tones of green, and I want to convert it to a red website. Is there a simple way to convert all the green colors to the corresponding colors in red? I don't want to do it manually (by eye) but it would be good to have a mathematical way to do it. So eventually I can program a script to convert them...

Additional info: The colors are in RGBA format.

Comment: Better ask in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css since this is only visual graphic related forum :)

Comment: @DesignPhoenix isn't RGB a visual graphic thing? The fact that i will then use the RBG value in CSS it should not matter... But i will update the question to avoid misunderstanding...

Comment: There are too many ways to do this. See [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/83869/23061) for more info

Comment: Tell me one :) the @Billy Kerr answer works but I have strange colors sometimes. But so far seems good to me...

Comment: while CSS is part of (web)design work, code implementation is sort of off topic here. It can be asked in [so].

Comment: In the future you might want to use something like LESS or SASS. You could store a color code in a variable, sprinkle it around and use various methods to change the color. So if you change the variable to another color it gets updated throughout. Here's a [SASS example about that](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/controlling-color-with-sass-color-functions). If it was me, I might just use a code editor to find and replace all occurrences of each shade with SASS variables and methods. It would require some work, but after that changing the color would be super easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple method might just be to swap the R and G channels. The resulting colours may be somewhat purplish depending on how much blue there is. To get warmer reds, you could also set the B channel to 00.

For example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use hue shift filtering. It's like rotating RGB color wheel. Photoshop users do it often, but it's also available for web site programmers.

Unfortunately I'm not a programmer, so I cannot write any plausible code for it. As little I know of which browsers really understand it. Check this article for a start: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

**BTW.** RGB color system as well as its polar coordinate variant HSB has a weakness: Hue shift affects apparent luminosity. That can be fixed by inserting a top layer with blending mode (also a common term for Photoshop and web programming) "luminosity". That layer has original colors. Lab and HCL color systems do not have that weakness.

Comment: Follow up to your answer, here is a JavaScript HSL slider. You should be able to pull the code if you inspect the page :) http://hslpicker.com/#c905ff

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to define the new color hex values I want and the values they are to replace.

Then merely use find and replace in a text editor to alter the hex values. Find [old] replace with [new].

Depending on the number of files and colors it *could* be a very quick thing. Some text editors will allow you to find/replace across a number of documents at one time. (I use BBEdit and can run find/replace on dozens of files at once)