# How to get a color scale representing reflected light

Tags: color, gradient, rgb, lighting-effects, reflection

I got this wonderful image below from the [Wikipedia page on Dodecahedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron). It shows a Tetroid rotating slowly. If you look carefully, it is clear that the assumption is that there is a light source somewhere outside the screen. If a face reflects  more light back to the observer, it appears brighter and if it reflects less light back, it appears darker. I have an idea about how I might get a metric for the amount of light a face is reflecting back at a certain rotation. I can also scale the metric to a value between 0 and 255 (which most color scales assume). However, how do I get the actual rgb values that look like a bright, reflective blue when the metric is high and the darkish blue when the metric is low?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/75417/how-to-make-a-given-color-a-bit-darker-or-lighter/75419#75419 and this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83866/generating-a-series-of-colors-between-two-colors/83869#83869

Comment: And this one too: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/inkscape-realistic-lighting-and-shading/90478#90478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found that the HSL color scale is meant exactly for this (with the 'L' standing for luminosity). So, I just make the L scale linearly with my face angle keeping H and S constant. Here is the Python code for doing this conversion -

```
def colorFromAngle2(angle):
   h = 136
   s = 118
   l = 96+64*angle/450
   r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h/255.0, l/255.0, s/255.0)
   r, g, b = [x*255.0 for x in r, g, b]
   return (int(r),int(g),int(b))
```

This leads to something like this -

[image]